# Unable to get the boundary of an object using opencv minAreaRect

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to draw a minimum bounding rectangle around an object in an image using openCV,

the cv2.minAreaRect is returning the rectangle of correct size but its orientation is off

Following is my codeSnippet

The following screentshot shows the image i am working 
[image]

In the next screenshot it shows the image with the detected border
[image]

According to the opencv documentation linked here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
 this should work

Comment: Please do not post code in image form. It is too hard to read. Write the code as text in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where()` returns things in the normal array index (row, column) order, but OpenCV expects points in (x, y) order, which is opposite to (row, column). This has the effect that you are flipping the points about the diagonal of the image.

Simply reverse the points by swapping the two columns. Better yet would just be to be more explicit with variables and not do everything on one line:

```py
y, x = np.where(binary == 0)
coords = np.column_stack((x, y))
```

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. I simply did a np.flip() to resolve the issue. But this is a better solution!